# Whether we can run ginkgo test cases using console input or test data in any file formats?

Tags: testing, ginkgo

I need to pass user data via console or any file formats to ginkgo test methods. Let me know the ways.

I am looking into Table Driven Tests, but I am looking for test data which is located outside of test case/scripts. Thanks for sharing the details. I can understand your statement, but it would be great to get some sample code to proceed, which is available.

Please find the sample test method:

```
It("Allow issuer to issue new commercial paper", func() {
    //invoke chaincode method from authority actor
    expectcc.ResponseOk(paperChaincode.Invoke(`issue`, &cpaper.IssueCommercialPaper{
        Issuer:       IssuerName,
        PaperNumber:  "0001",
        IssueDate:    time.Now(),
        MaturityDate: time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 24 * 30 * 6), // Six months later
        FaceValue:    100000,
    }))
})
```

Comment: What have you tried yet?

Comment: I am new to this. Started exploring on this.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow then. Maybe you will want to have a look at the gingko cli documentation here https://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/#the-ginkgo-cli . You may also want to have a look at how Stackoverflow works here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . We will be happy to help with any specific problem that you will run into as long as you provide your code. We can not, though, provide finished solutions.